# "sed: can't read {config_path}: No such file or directory" incluso cuando ya he definido las variables

Tags: sed

Verán, tengo este error extraño de sed "sed: can't read {config_path}: No such file or directory" incluso cuando ya he definido las variables.
Estoy trabajando en Google Colab.

dejo una captura de un código de ejemplo que reproduce el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué creen que sea? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Parece que la variable `config_path` no está definida. Prueba ejecutando nuevamente la celda 3, y luego la que tiene el código sed.